# Keras model.inputs not saving names

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a saved Keras model defined as follows:

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
query.appliance_slot.asr_hyp [(None, None)]            0         
_________________________________________________________________
query.appliance_slot.asr_hyp [(None, None)]            0         
_________________________________________________________________
query.appliance_slot.asr_hyp [(None, None)]            0         
_________________________________________________________________
query.appliance_slot.asr_hyp [(None, None)]            0         
_________________________________________________________________
query.appliance_slot.asr_hyp [(None, None)]            0         
_________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_stack (TensorFlo multiple                  0         

...
```

and the actual model definition code involves the input layers:

```
            asr_query_input_1 = tf.keras.Input(
                shape=(None,), name="query.appliance_slot.asr_hyp_1", dtype=tf.int32
            )
            asr_query_input_2 = tf.keras.Input(
                shape=(None,), name="query.appliance_slot.asr_hyp_2", dtype=tf.int32
            )
            asr_query_input_3 = tf.keras.Input(
                shape=(None,), name="query.appliance_slot.asr_hyp_3", dtype=tf.int32
            )
```

However, when I try loading this saved model, and examining the `model.inputs`, I see the input layers have had their names changed to generic ones:

```
>>> model.inputs

[<tf.Tensor 'input_1_1:0' shape=(None, None) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'input_2_1:0' shape=(None, None) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'input_3_1:0' shape=(None, None) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'input_4_1:0' shape=(None, None) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'input_5_1:0' shape=(None, None) dtype=int32>,
...
```

This is causing an issue with passing input into the model via a dictionary via TFRecords. Anyone know why this issue is occurring?

---

Additional info:

Note that I have isolated this issue to the model saving and loading process; when I run `model.inputs` on a freshly built model, I see the correct behavior:

```
[<tf.Tensor 'query.appliance_slot.asr_hyp_1:0' shape=(None, None) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'query.appliance_slot.asr_hyp_2:0' shape=(None, None) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'query.appliance_slot.asr_hyp_3:0' shape=(None, None) dtype=int32>, ...
```

Model saving and loading code:

Saving:

```
model.save(full_path, save_format="tf")
```

Loading:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_artifacts_folder)
```

Comment: Can you share how you are saving and loading back the model?

Comment: Sure, I'll update the post

Comment: Interesting, I have further isolated the issue to a specific choice of architecture (i.e. when I add this architectural modification, then the issue with the input layer naming occurs; when I turn this feature off, the model saving works again). Will update as I continue to investigate

Comment: OK, I identified the precise issue: I have a custom layer which seems to mess up the node connectivity of the computational graph, since I don't think I follow the proper tensorflow keras layer conventions

Comment: Ok, so ultimately the issue is quite simple - it is just that the computational graph that is deserialized is different than the one that was serialized

Comment: OK, I figured out the problem after spending the day troubleshooting - it is because I did not override the `get_config` method in my custom layer class.